# Words in first column moving in another column in tabular section

Tags: tables, two-column

[image: SAE Levels]When I am writing a word in column, at some places the last word of the first column is merging with the second column.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you please edit your post and include a MWE as I find it currently a bit hard to understand where your problem lies. Thank you.

Comment: it is not merging it is simply overfull and overprinting set the cells with `\raggedright` jusified textt makes over-stretched spaces even when not overflowing, as your image shows.